# Word VSTO Add-In on Visual Studio. Why can't I open the Ribbon Visual Designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto, windows-forms-designer

On computer "A", I successfully developed a Word VSTO Add-In using VS 2019 Enterprise using C#. Recently, I rebuilt the hard disk on computer "A". Reinstalled Windows 10 (version 1909). Reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise (currently 16.5.5) including the Office/Sharepoint development workload.

On the rebuilt computer "A", I created a new VSTO Word Add-In project. Added a Ribbon (Visual Designer) to the project using this guide: [Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)

[image]

When I attempt to open the designer for the Ribbon I get a no-information error message:

[image]

No errors in the error list.

When I attempt to open the ribbon designer on the original, working VSTO add-in, same thing happens.

I have computer "B" that is configured the same as was computer "A" before I rebuilt computer "A". On computer "B", I'm able to open the ribbon designer successfully for both a new VSTO project and my original VSTO project. I compared computer "A" references to computer "B" reference and they look the same

[image]

Also verified that Office Runtime is installed

[image]

I assume I'm missing a reference. Anyone experience this? Any ideas?

Other things I tried: deleting \bin. Cleaned, rebuilt solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be a mystery. I ended up rebuilding the machine a second time. The only difference was that the second time around I installed Office 2016 instead of Office 2019. I was able to open the ribbon designer just fine this time around